Why end final positions don't appear?
I am running relax calculation for a 2D material using Quantum ESPRESSO code. However, after job is done the "end final coordinates" don't appear. What can I addjust?
Greetings.

Isn't it 'End final coordinates' rather than 'end final positions'?

Inspect the log file if there are any warnings or errors reported during the calculation. You can also restart the calculation with different optimization constraints or a different plane wave cutoff, just to see if that helps.
